# The name "Settings" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyApp.Properties"

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, namespaces, settings.settings

In my C# / WPF app, I'm trying to bind some UI element properties to the settings. I'm talking about the settings that I have defined in Properties/Settings.settings.
These settings all have the User scope, and the Access modifier is set to Public.

I managed to do that in another app some time ago, and I didn't have any problem, so I don't know what is wrong this time.

I'm getting this error while building: The name "Settings" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:MyApp.Properties"

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.SettingsWindow"
...
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:MyApp.Properties">
...
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=Blah}">Some text</CheckBox>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

False alert. There was actually another legit error at the end of the error list, which was causing the build to fail.
The binding I described above works fine, it's just some Intelli-non-sense...

Comment: Instead of answering you could have deleted the question.

Comment: It can still help someone in the same situation. It gives a hint to look at the other errors in the list before tring to solve this non-issue.